# What exactly is dplyr doing with filter() in case of multiple conditions?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, logic

E.g.,
library(dplyr)

```r
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,1),b = c(21,28,35,42,49))
df[(df$a != 1 & df$b != 49), ]
df[!(df$a == 1 & df$b == 49), ]
df %>% filter(a != 1 & b != 49)
```

How does it come that

```
df[(df$a != x & df$b != y), ]
```

leads to different results than

```
df[!(df$a == x & df$b == y), ]
```

?

And the more practical question:
What is the equivalent of

```
df[!(df$a == 1 & df$b == 49), ]
```

for dplyr's filter()?

Comment: Your 2nd and 4th line of code `filter` is giving the same result

Comment: Perhaps you need `df[!(df$a == 1 | df$b == 49), ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent in `dplyr` is

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     filter(!(a == 1 & b == 49))
```

---

Regarding the difference between

```
out1 <- df[(df$a != 1 & df$b != 49), ]
out2 <- df[!(df$a == 1 & df$b == 49), ]
```

With 'out1', if we split up the code

```
df$a != 1
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

df$b != 49
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

When we do `&` operator, only corresponding elements that are `TRUE` becomes TRUE in the output

```
df$a != 1 & df$b != 49
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

In the second case,

```
df$a == 1 & df$b == 49
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

When it is negated `!`, TRUE -> FALSE, FALSE ->TRUE

resulting in 4 rows selected, while in the former only 3 rows selected

An option would be `|` instead of `&`

```
df$a == 1 | df$b == 49
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Negating

```
!(df$a == 1 | df$b == 49)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```